# Filtering CSV files by multiple columns, sort them and create 2 new files

Tags: csv, awk, filtering

I have been searching how to do the following for couple hours and could not find it. I apologize if I am repeating something.
  I have 22 csv files with 14 columns and 17,392 lines in each.I am using awk to filter the original files using the following commands:

First need to get lines that have values on column 14 smaller than 0.05

```
awk -F '\t' '$14 < 0.05  { print $0 }' file1 > file2
```

Next I need to get the lines with values higher and 1 and smaller than -1.

```
awk -F '\t' '$10 < -1 { print $0 }' file2 > file3
awk -F '\t' '$10 > 1 { print $0 }' file2 > file4
```

My last step is to get the lines that have values on column 7 OR 8 higher than 1 (e.g. on 7 could be 0 if on 8 it is 1)

```
awk -F '\t' '$7<=1 {print $0}' file3 > file5
awk -F '\t' '$8>=1 {print $0}' file4 > file6
```

My problem is that I create several intermediate files. I would need just two files at the end. File3 and 4 where columns 7 or 8 have values equal or greater than 1. How can I make an awk command to do that at once?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous, so there are many possible answers.  However, you can combine conditions in `awk` and you can write to separate files in a single pass, so you might mean:

```
awk -F '\t' '$14 < 0.05 && $10 < -1 && $7 > 1 { print > "file5" }
             $14 < 0.05 && $10 > +1 && $8 > 1 { print > "file6" }' file1
```

This command should give you the same output in `file5` and `file6` as you got from your original sequence of operations (but it only makes one pass over the data, not many).  *(Strictly, it produces the same answer if you change your `$7<=1` to `$7>1` to agree with your description of wanting `column 7 or 8 higher than 1`, though that contradicts your example 'on 7 could be 0 if on 8 it is 1'.)*

Given an input file:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    -10  11   12   13   -14
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   -14
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14
```

The output in `file5` is:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    -10  11   12   13   -14
```

and the output in `file6` is:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   -14
```

If you need to combine the conditions differently, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I apologize if it was a confusing question. However your suggestion did exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much it will save a lot of time. Regarding to the values on column 7 and 8, I just don't want to print lines where the values are smaller than one in both columns. So it's okay to have small values in one column as long as the other column the value is equals or greater than one. It is gene expression data, so we want genes that are at least expressed in one sample above a minimal threshold. Column 7 and 8 are two samples.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk -F'\t' '($14 < 0.05) && ($10 < -1) && ($7 <= 1) {print}' file1 > file3
```

Comment: Hi thank you. When I run your command it gives me a file where the column 7 and 8 have the values smaller than 1. I think i was so very clear in my question. The suggestion gave by @Jonathan worked.